# How to change value of a node field after a webform is submitted?

Tags: nodes, webforms

I have a content type "items" with a Select list field with the options 0|Free and 1|Reserved.

I am trying to change the fields value from 0 (default) to 1 when a certain webform is submitted (the webform gets the Nid from the url).

For this I have made (and enabled) a custom module (by following a tutorial I found) with the code below:

```
function reservable_item_change_status_webform_submission_insert($node,$submission) {
  if($node->nid == 5){ //my webform has an id of 5
    $nodeID = $submission->data[3]['value']['0'];
    $reservableItem = node_load($nodeID);
    if($reservableItem ->type == 'items'){
      $reservableItem->field_item_status['und'][0]['value'] = 1;
      node_save($reservableItem);
    }
  }
}
```

My problem is that nothing is happening. No errors, but the field status is not being changed to reserved.

I am using Webform version 3.2 because the tutorial stated it was meant for Webform 3.x. I will test with 4.x after I get this working.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For anyone else trying to get similar functionality to work in Webform 4.x you need to change $nodeID = $submission->data[3]['value']['0']; to $nodeID = $submission->data[3]['0']; as mentioned in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If typo:

```
if($reservableItem ->type == 'items'){
```

change into:

```
if($reservableItem->type == 'items'){
```

In my implementation I get the submission values like:

```
$submission->data[3][0]
```

So try to change it accordingly

Comment: Thanks for comment. I actually tried this both ways (cause was wondering the same thing). The way I wrote it here was how it was in the tutorial. But this didn't fix the issue.

Comment: I tried $submission->data[3][0]. Same problem. Maybe the hook is not working at all for some reason?

Comment: are you sure that node id is under `$submission->data[3]` ? It schould be in 3th input field in webform then

Comment: It is the 3rd input field in the webform. I'm just wondering how I start to debug this problem.. to see if the hook is working at all.

Comment: Turns out I had a typo in the filename of the .module file.. this is the first module I am making so didn't really know what to check. I thank you for your help! Also the typo you mentioned in the answer was important (you suggested the correct way).

Comment: Also, for anyone else trying to get similar functionality. Your implementation of getting submission values ($submission->data[3][0]) is required to make this work with Webform 4.x ($submission->data[3]['value']['0'] returns an php error).